# Weird behavior of reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

I just found a bug in my code of using reinterpret_cast, after I change it to dynamic_cast, the problem is gone. I then try to re-produce the behavior using the following code:

```
  1 #include <iostream>
  2
  3 using namespace std;
  4
  5 typedef enum {
  6     ONE, TWO,
  7 } Num;
  8
  9 class B {
 10     public:
 11         virtual Num f() const = 0;
 12 };
 13
 14 class D: public B {
 15     public:
 16         virtual Num f() const { return TWO; }
 17 };
 18
 19 int main()
 20 {
 21     B *b = new D();
 22     cout << "f()=" << reinterpret_cast<D*>(b)->f() << endl << endl;
 23
 24     return 0;
 25 }
```

This code is simplified version of the bug I just fixed, basically I try to re-produce the bug so that if I do not replace reinterpret_cast with dynamic_cast, a wild enum number is returned in line 22; after I change it to dynamic_cast, the the right enum is returned.

BUT the above code actually runs good, it does prints out "1" which is enum TWO.

Maybe my simplification has some problem, but do you see any chance the above code may have problem using reinterpret_case?

Yes, I know using reinterpret_case does not make sense, it is just I like to know what is going on.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing this because the `B` that is contained in a `D` does not exist at the same address. This probably has to do with the implementation of virtual method dispatch tables. The language makes no such guarantee since neither `B` nor `D` are POD types.

`reinterpret_cast` is basically you telling the compiler "take the bit pattern of this value and treat it as some other type, without changing it."

> You touched [on] something which is what I am looking for, about the dispatch table, but it is not so clear, can you elaborate?

C++ does not dictate the particulars of a compiler's and/or ABI's implementation. Thus it's not guaranteed that `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` will do the same thing. You've stumbled onto a case (single-inheritance hierarchy, as AndreyT pointed out) where it does on your compiler.

When you declare a class as having `virtual` members, it's no longer a POD type where the stored object's contents are exactly as written in the class declaration, because the compiler adds a hidden "virtual table pointer" to the start of storage. This pointer points to a per-class table containing the particulars of that class's virtual members, such as function pointers pointing to the virtual methods for that class. For example, you wrote:

```
class B {
    public:
        virtual Num f() const = 0;
};
```

but what is stored for a `B` is probably something like:

```
struct __VirtualsForB {
    Num (*f)(const B* this);
};

struct B {
    const __VirtualsForB* const __vtbl;
};
```

Then you write:

```
class D: public B {
    public:
        // BTW, don't need to say `virtual` here. Virtual-ness is inherited.
        virtual Num f() const { return TWO; }
};
```

and storage for *that* looks like:

```
struct __VirtualsForD {
    __VirtualsForB __super;
};

// This exists since D is not abstract.
extern const __VirtualsForD __virtuals_for_D;

struct D {
    const __VirtualsForD* const __vtbl;
};
```

Also, the compiler auto-generates some code and your virtual method (which probably can't be inlined even though you wrote it that way, since there needs to be a pointer to it for the virtual table to work):

```
Num __D__f(const B* __in_this)
{
    const D* this = static_cast<const D*>(__in_this);
    return TWO;
}

const __VirtualsForD __virtuals_for_D = { __D__f } ;
```

Then when you write:

```
B *b = new D();
```

*that* turns into something like:

```
// Allocate a D.
D* _new_D = (D*)operator new(sizeof(D));
// Construct the D.
_new_D.__vtbl = __virtuals_for_D;
B *b = static_cast<B*>(_new_D);
```

And due to some coincidental facts of this implementation:

1. The first thing in the virtual table for `D` is the virtual table for `B`.
2. The first thing in a `B` or `D` is a pointer to the object's class's virtual table.

it *just so happens* that `reinterpret_cast` and `dynamic_cast` do the same thing (namely, nothing) and your `cout << reinterpret_cast<D*>(b)->f()` succeeds. Which, by the way, turns into something like:

```
B* __temp = static_cast<B*>(reinterpret_cast<D*>(b));
Num __temp2 = (*__temp.__vtbl.f)(__temp);
std::ostream::operator<<(cout, __temp2);
// ...
```

If either of these conditions were not true, as is often the case in multiple inheritance or inheritance with virtual base classes, then `reinterpret_cast` would fail like you expected it to.

This is literally **implementation-defined behavior.**

Comment: You touches something which is what I am looking for, about the dispatch table, but it is not so clear, can you elaborate?

Comment: Also have a question: Num __D__f(const B* __in_this), I wonder why the argument is B*. Is it because the compiler sees that there is an implicit conversion needed? If so, suppose it is a deeper hierarchy tree and there is grandchild class, G which has an object pointed by a B pointer, in that case, there will be another name-mangled f() function taking G as argument?

Comment: I got it from one too many debugging sessions, where I had my program dump the raw byte values in memory just to see what was going on. Buffer overflow failures have all kinds of crazy effects, and an object's `__vtbl` suddenly pointing somewhere it didn't when it was created is a good sign of Very Bad Things Happening.

Comment: In `Num __D__f(const B* __in_this)` the argument is a `B*` instead of a `D*` because the virtual method's signature must match the one in the base class in which it was declared. The code calling that method *might have no idea* if the object is a `B` or some subclass thereof. (Remember, there's the possibility that `B` and `D` are declared in entirely different header files, and the compiler might never see the one with `D`.)

Comment: BTW, if you use gcc or a derivative, you can use the `objdump -dtCw <linked-program-name> > <program-name>.s` command (fill in the <> bracketed bits as appropriate) to get an assembly dump to see what's really going on. Warning: there are a *lot* of other things going on that I've omitted for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` will not handle the type dispatch correctly. If you already know the type you want to use, then use `static_cast`. If you don't know the type you want to use, then use `dynamic_cast` and make sure the pointer returned by `dynamic_cast` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

In a single-inheritance hierarchy, when the very top class of the hierarchy is already polymorphic, all casts along the hierarchy do the same thing: nothing. They just "conceptually" reinterpret the pointer value as a value of different type. Only `dynamic_cast` will perform some additional checks when used for downcasts.

For this reason `reinterpret_cast` happens to "work" for this purpose. And there's no way to force it not to work, given your class definitions.